# Finding sum of square of two numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays

My program should take a number from the user, and find the two numbers in an array such that the sum of their squares equals the user input squared. However, I'm having trouble doing this, as well as understanding all the errors I'm getting.

Here's my current attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int numberaa;
scanf("%d",&numberaa);
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int array[9] = {2,-4,6,3,9,0,-1,-9};
    for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= 8; J++0)
            firstone==i*i
            secondone==j*j
            if {
                firstone+secondone=numberaa;
                printf("The Numbers are %d and %d",j,i,numberaa);
                return 0
            };
```

Comment: That's a weird way of indentation. If that's what you indent your code, I suggest you learning some good coding style, after learning C basics, of course. It's hard to tell you what you did wrong, because there are too many. It's better to read some book first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
firstone+secondone=numberaa;
```

to

```
numberaa = firstone + secondone;
```

Ah! You need to grab a basic C book. For this time I am posting a correct code for you. Hope you will learn something.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int array[9] = {2,-4,6,3,9,0,-1,-9};
    int numberaa;
    scanf("%d",&numberaa);

    for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++){
        for (j = 0; j <= 8; J++0){
            firstone = i*i
            secondone = j*j
            if(numberaa == firstone + secondone)
                  printf("The Numbers are %d and %d",j,i,numberaa);
        }
    }
    return 0 
}
```

Comment: The `scanf("%d",&numberaa);` line isn't going to work either I think.

Comment: There's an error on almost every line.  I'm certain that you'll end up rewriting the code if you were to fix it in entirety.

Comment: Yes, that is true. He has to learn the basics of C first, before asking questions here. I'm down-voting.

Comment: @devnull; Exactly I am doing that :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to read through at least the introductory chapter of a book on C and **work through the examples**.  That means typing them out (no, don't copy and paste), compiling them, and running them to understand what makes them work and what breaks them.

When you write your own code, always compile with warnings enabled, e.g. `gcc -Wall -o my_executable_name my_code.c`, and pay attention to the line numbers referenced in compiler errors and warnings.

I'll point out some locations of errors in your code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int numberaa;  // Currently you're declaring this as a global.  NO! not what you want.
scanf("%d",&numberaa); // This isn't going to happen out here.  NO! NO NO NO!

int main()  // Specify your parameters.  int main(void)
{
  int i,j;
  int array[9] = {2,-4,6,3,9,0,-1,-9};  // why specify an array of 9 but store just 8 elements??
  for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++) // These are the correct limits for array[9].
    for (j = 0; j <= 8; J++0)  // j and J are not the same.  What is J++0 ????!!  Also, read about "blocks" and try a for-loop example with more than one line.
        firstone==i*i  // WTF??  Have you even tried to compile this? 
        secondone==j*j // See line above.
        if {  // Likewise
            firstone+secondone=numberaa; // Likewise again.
    printf("The Numbers are %d and %d",j,i,numberaa);  // How many formatting flags does your first argument have, and how many are to be inserted?
    return 0 };  // again, have you tried to compile this?
```

Short version:

- Semicolons
- Assignment vs. equality
- Scope of variables
- Blocks, brace usage
- syntax of `if` statements
- You also aren't squaring the user input.
- Efficiency:  you only need to calculate `firstone = i * i` once for each `i` value, so take it outside the `j` loop.